# Using awk to get the maximum value of a column, for each unique value of another column

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, uniq

So I have a file such as:

```
10 1 abc
10 2 def
10 3 ghi
20 4 elm
20 5 nop
20 6 qrs
30 3 tuv
```

I would like to get the maximum value of the second column for each value of the first column, i.e.:

```
10 3 ghi
20 6 qrs
30 3 tuv
```

How can I do using `awk` or similar unix commands?

Comment: Are the lines always in incrementing order of 2nd column and wit the first column always organized with common values next to each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$2>max[$1]{max[$1]=$2; row[$1]=$0} END{for (i in row) print row[i]}' file
```

**Output:**

```
10 3 ghi
20 6 qrs
30 3 tuv
```

**Explanation:**

awk command uses an associative array `max` with key as `$1` and value as `$2`. Every time we encounter a value already stored in this associative array `max`, we update our previous entry and store whole row in another associative array `row` with the same key. Finally in `END` section we simply iterate over associative array `row` and print it.

Comment: This gives what was asked for.  I would suggest to store `$0` instead of just `$3` for each maximum line.  This would simplify the printing at the end and would work for a number of fields >3 (even a variable number of fields).

Comment: Thank you very much @anubhava for your quick answer. Can you please provide an explanation about the code? Also, Thank you e0k for the generalization, it was very useful for my needs.

Comment: Added an explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

shorter alternative with `sort`

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | sort -u -k1,1

10 3 ghi
20 6 qrs
30 3 tuv
```

sort by field one and field two (numeric, reverse) so that max for each key will be top of the group, pick the first for each key by the second sort.